# Oracle rolling LEAD calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Is it possible in Oracle to have a rolling lead calculation?
I have a table where the first row is set to 100%. Every row after that equals the previous percentage multiplied by a factor, in this example o.99978.
I can only get answer for first row without rolling all the way down.
seq 3 should equal 0.99956 and so on.

```
SELECT SEQ, 
(CASE WHEN SEQ = 1 THEN PERC LAG(PERC) OVER (ORDER BY SEQ) * FACTOR END) 
PERC
FROM 
(SELECT 1 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, 1 PERC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, NULL PERC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, NULL PERC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, NULL PERC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, NULL PERC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, NULL PERC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, NULL PERC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, NULL PERC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, NULL PERC FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10 SEQ, 0.99978 FACTOR, NULL PERC FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: You have pasted an Excel screenshot in your question, which doesn't mean much from a SQL point of view.  Please include your sample data/output directly in the question, and do _not_ paste links.

Comment: So, are you saying that in general the factors don't need to be equal? If they are always the same factor, it's a trivial computation (someone already posted an answer for that special case).

Comment: And - just to be clear - in each row you multiply the "perc" from the previous row by the "factor" in the **current** row, right? So the "factor" from the first row is irrelevant - it is never used, correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct the first factor is irrelevant. In this instance the factor stays the same, eventually we will have e.g. 6 different products each with 100 steps. The factor will be consistent for every step belonging to a particular product but different for each product

Comment: OK, but the calculation is done for each product separately, or do you need to mix together factors from different products in the same calculation? If the factor is constant for each calculation (meaning, each product has its own calculation), then you can rewrite the needed value using powers of the factor (even if the factor is specific to each product) and not need any kind of analytic functions. You can adapt the answer posted by DDS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
select seq, factor, power(factor,seq-1) as perc
from my_table
```

where your table is like the one in the picture with only first two columns

here an [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=372e9bbe4f16977a380e8806c3e54039) on dbfiddle

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Gerard This will only work when the factor is the same in every row.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a `PRODUCT()` aggregate/analytic function in Oracle but you can get the same effect (with a few rounding errors) using `EXP(SUM(LN(value)))` and to get a cumulative product you can use the `SUM( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY ... [RANGE|ROWS] BETWEEN ... )` windowed analytic function.

This demonstrates how to perform the calculation where the values are not the same in every row:

```
WITH test_data ( SEQ, FACTOR ) AS (
  SELECT  1, 0.99978 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  2, 0.99978 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 0.99978 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  4, 0.99978 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  5, 0.99978 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  6, 0.99978 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  7, 0.99900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  8, 0.99978 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  9, 0.99978 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 0.99978 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SEQ,
       FACTOR,
       EXP(
         COALESCE(
           SUM( LN( FACTOR ) ) OVER ( ORDER BY SEQ ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ),
           LN(1)
         )
       ) AS PERC
FROM   test_data;
```

**Output**:

```
SEQ | FACTOR |                                      PERC
--: | -----: | ----------------------------------------:
  1 | .99978 |                                         1
  2 | .99978 | .9997799999999999999999999999999999999907
  3 | .99978 | .9995600483999999999999999999999999999915
  4 | .99978 | .9993401451893519999999999999999999999783
  5 | .99978 | .9991202903574103425599999999999999999725
  6 | .99978 | .9989004838935317122846367999999999999711
  7 |   .999 | .9986807257870751353079341799039999999662
  8 | .99978 | .9976820450612880601726262457240959999696
  9 | .99978 | .9974625550113745767993882679500366988414
 10 | .99978 | .9972431132492720743924924025310876907504
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=259936ea6784d7ef9b1bbce1204a8aad)*